get list of all projects present in my foundry platform
I'm trying to get a list of all the projects created on my foundry instance.

Is there any system tables that i can access directly to get the list
I tried to get the list using API call, but not able to get the correct endpoint

payload = {"directRoleGrantPrincipalIds":{},"organizations":[],"pageSize":500,"query":"","roles":[],"sort":{"direction":"ASC","field":"NAME"},"tags":[],"decorations":["alias"]}

requests.post(https://domainname.com/compass/api/search/projects, headers=headers, json=payload)

this works but is limited to only first 500 records because of page size. I tried to increase the page size and run the command, but its still limited to 500

Pagination requires a start offset and page size.
The fetched records will have a number of page size records starting from provided offset.

Please try specifying start offset in your request payload.
You may specify pageToken in payload as mentioned in document https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/api/general/overview/paging/.
Response will have nextPageToken
response = requests.post()

payload = {
  "directRoleGrantPrincipalIds":{},
  "organizations":[],
  "pageSize":500,
  "query":"",
  "roles":[],
  "sort":{"direction":"ASC","field":"NAME"},
  "tags":[],
  "decorations":["alias"],
  "pageToken": response["nestPageToken"]
}


Can you please help me with changing payload? Not getting the specific tag to add to it

Response will have nextPageToken. Please try passing that as pageToken https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/api/general/overview/paging/.
response = requests.post()
payload = {
"directRoleGrantPrincipalIds":{},
"organizations":[],
"pageSize":500,
"query":"",
"roles":[],
"sort":{"direction":"ASC","field":"NAME"},
"tags":[],
"decorations":["alias"],
"pageToken": response[nestPageToken]
}
